# Частичная специализация C++

Tags: c++, классы, терминология, шаблоны-с++

Почему этот пример считается частичной специализацией:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class A { };

template <typename T>
class A <T, T> { };
```

Ведь в нем не идет замена параметров шаблона конкретными типами или константными выражениями?

Comment: По-видимому потому что T1 и T2 предполагаются разные, но второй кусок делает их одинаковыми.

Comment: @0andriy но разве тогда не будет это считаться полной специализацией?

Comment: Неполная, очевидно, потому что в шаблоне (то есть нет строго определённого типа).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Специализация которая начинается с `template<parameters-list>` называется "частичной",
специализация которая начинается с `template<>` называется "полной".